# React-Table Filtering unexpected behavior : The table header is updated (and the filter itself) instead of updating just the data

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I'm using React@16.13.1, React-Table@7.2.1 and Axios@0.19.2, to create a table with out of the box server side pagination and filtering.
The pagination is working fine but I'm having some difficulties with the filtering. I have two default text filters that filter correctly (they get the correct info from the server), but I'm experiencing strange behaviours:

- On key press, when the filtering is done (when the axios request gets an answer), the table is totally refreshed including the header where the filters are (and not only its results);
- Since it refreshes the whole table, the textbox where the user was typing looses the focus, and forces the user to reselect the filter to introduce the second character.

For the filtering, I'm using the DefaultColumnFilter that React-Table offers:

```
function DefaultColumnFilter({ column: { filterValue, setFilter, id } }) {
  return (
    <input
      value={filterValue || ""}
      onChange={e => {
        setFilter(e.target.value || undefined)
      }}
      placeholder={`Rechercher ...`}
    />
  )
}
```

So, my questions are:

- How can I stop the auto filtering after just one char is typed (I've tried to use a setTimeout, but couldn't set it to work correctly...)?
- How to make it stop refreshing the whole table including the header?

I've created a sandbox with the relevant code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-shape-3tbn7

Comment: This may sound obvious but it sounds like you need a more complex `useEffect` that only sends the Axios request when the input value's length is more that 1, and creating sub-components for the header and body of the table, so that you can make use of somthing like `shouldComponentUpdate` to conditionally re-render each specific one based on props.

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi, thank you for your contribution. Although that could be a "last resource" solution, what is really intended is that only the table's data is updated, not the filter textbox. That way we can have realtime filtering on every key-up event.

Comment: @LuisGouveia isn't that what I suggested? If I'm not mistaken, the filter textbox is part of the header, and the data is part of the body, so if you make those separate components, you can make it so the header only updates when key strokes on the inputs, and the body only updates when the data array has changed.

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi, ok, I didn't understand you intended to split the components, I thought that you wanted to do exactly what we're already doing but only on enter, instead of key-up. Yes, that could be a solution, but it's very customised. I would like us to keep using the react-table's DefaultColumnFilter, it should be possible to implement filtering without refreshing the header. I cannot believe such a popular library has such a serious bug, we must be doing something wrong. I just didn't figure out what!

Comment: @LuisGouveia you can still use **react-table** with my suggestion, what I exactly meant is instead of rendering `<thead>` with all its children there like you are doing now, you render a component that you create called something like `<BTableHead>` that wraps the `<thead>` and take its contents as props, and you configure it to only re-render if something in your `headerGroups` changed. And you do the same for `<tbody>`. That's what I meant, now I'm not sure if that's still too "customized" as you said.

Answer (score 0):

We finally understood the problem. It was not related with react-table. **React-table is perfectly capable of doing server-side filtering out-of-the-box.**

The problem was here. We had:

```
// Render the UI for your table
if (pageLoading) return <Loading />
```

pageLoading was activated by filtering, and so we replaced it by:

```
// Render the UI for your table
if (loading) return <Loading />
```

We were 'erasing' the HTML of our table every time we used the filters. We were replacing the table by a loading bar '' at that moment.

Now we are using a different variable (loading) that is not activated by filtering. It works like a charm!